# using-declarations of std functions on namespace scope

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

I'd like to have your opinion on the following piece of code:

```
// LIBRARY_HEADER.hpp

#include <cmath>

namespace NS {

using std::sqrt;

template<class T> T foo(T x) { return sqrt(x); }

}
```

The function `foo` can now be called with fundamental and user-defined types (for which there is a `sqrt` in their resp. namespace). The using-declaration can also be put inside foo. However if there are a lot of foos (and I have a lot of them), then writing `using std::sqrt` in every function body becomes tedious. So I have decided to put this using-declaration in namespace scope, even if it is in an header file, which is included by a potentially large and unknown number of users.
Some notes:

- It is a using-declaration and I use it only for functions, not a using-directive.
- It is itself put in namespace `NS`, so it should not interfere with user code (not even, if they write `using namespace NS`).

This approach saves me a lot of LOC.
Still, I have mixed feelings about it. But maybe only because we were drilled not to use `using namespace std` in header files, which is clearly not the point here.

Is this a bad idea nevertheless? Are there rational arguments against my approach?

Comment: Doing `using namespace NS;` in some scope will also bring `std::sqrt` into that scope.

Comment: `NS::sqrt(42);` would call `std::sqrt(42);`